# pandas dataframe data sorting

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset which looks like following-

```
|      year     |     state   |district| Party|
|---------------|-------------|--------|------|
|          2010 |     haryana |kaithal | INC|
|          2010 |     haryana |kaithal | bjp|
|          2010 |     haryana |kaithal |NOTA|
|          2010 |     goa     |panji   | AAP|
|          2010 |     goa     |panji   | INC|
|          2010 |     goa     |panji   | BJP|
|          2013 |     up      |meerut  | INC|
|          2013 |     up      |meerut  | SP |
|          2015 |     haryana |kaithal |INC |
|          2015 |     haryana |kaithal |BJP |
|          2015 |     haryana |kaithal |AAP |
```

I want to rename INC to major for year 2010 and BJP to major in 2015. I need data in the following manner-

| year | state | district | Party |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 | haryana | kaithal | major |
| 2010 | haryana | kaithal | bjp |
| 2010 | haryana | kaithal | NOTA |
| 2010 | goa | panji | AAP |
| 2010 | goa | panji | major |
| 2010 | goa | panji | BJP |
| 2013 | up | meerut | major |
| 2013 | up | meerut | SP |
| 2015 | haryana | kaithal | INC |
| 2015 | haryana | kaithal | major |
| 2015 | haryana | kaithal | AAP |

I am using the code-

```
for state in df['state']:
  if state=='haryana':
    for year in df['year']:
      if year==2010:
        df['party'].replace('INC','major',inplace=True)
      else:
         continue
      if year==2015:
        df['party'].replace('BJP','major',inplace=True)
  else:
    continue
```

But this code is taking a lot of time to run and not giving the desired results as it is just considering replacing INC to major in all years and does not replace BJP.

Comment: Do you need match only if `df.state=='haryana'` ?

Comment: because also replacement  if `df.state=='goa'` or `df.state=='up'`

Comment: What is your complete code? `if state=='haryana':` is wrong there in question?

Comment: the code i have written is not working. It was just a sample for one state, to know if there is some mistake there. I am trying your solution, it is not giving the required results. I am using m1=(df['STATE']=='BIHAR') & (df['YEAR']==2010) & ((df['PARTY']=='BJP')|(df['PARTY']=='JD(U)'))
m2=(df['STATE']=='BIHAR') & (df['YEAR']==2015) & ((df['PARTY']=='RJD')|(df['PARTY']=='JD(U)'))
m3=(df['STATE']=='BIHAR') & (df['YEAR']==2020) & ((df['PARTY']=='BJP')|(df['PARTY']=='JD(U)'))
m=m1|m2|m3
df.loc[m, 'PARTY']= 'MAJOR'    this is making all three parties major in all three years.

Comment: One idea, if check `print (df[df['PARTY']=='JD(U)')])` return correct rows?

Comment: yes, it does return correct rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chain 3 conditions for compare each 3 values and set new values in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
m1 = (df.state=='haryana') & (df['year'] == 2010) & (df['party'] == 'INC')
m2 = (df.state=='haryana') & (df['year'] == 2015) & (df['party'] == 'BJP')
m = m1 | m2
```

Or:

```
m = (df.state=='haryana') & ((df['year'] == 2010) & (df['party'] == 'INC') |
                             (df['year'] == 2015) & (df['party'] == 'BJP'))

df.loc[m, 'party'] = 'major'
```

EDIT: You can check ouput of masks if working well:

```
m1=(df['STATE']=='BIHAR') & (df['YEAR']==2010) & ((df['PARTY']=='BJP')|(df['PARTY']=='JD(U)')) 
m2=(df['STATE']=='BIHAR') & (df['YEAR']==2015) & ((df['PARTY']=='RJD')|(df['PARTY']=='JD(U)')) 
m3=(df['STATE']=='BIHAR') & (df['YEAR']==2020) & ((df['PARTY']=='BJP')|(df['PARTY']=='JD(U)')) m=m1|m2|m3 df.loc[m, 'PARTY']= 'MAJOR'

print (df.assign(m1=m1, m2=m2, m3=m3,triple= m1 | m2 | m3,
                BIHAR = (df['STATE']=='BIHAR'),
                Y2010 = (df['YEAR']==2010)))
```

Comment: In the expected output shared by the OP, where `state=="goa"`, `INC` got replaced by `major`.

Comment: @abokey - ggod point, I ask OP  in comments

Answer (score 2):

You can use [*boolean indexing*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html) with [`pandas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) :

```
m1= (df["year"].eq(2010)) & (df["Party"].eq("INC"))
m2= (df["year"].eq(2015)) & (df["Party"].eq("BJP"))
​
df.loc[m1|m2, "Party"] = "major"
```

##### # Ouptut :

```
  print(df.to_string())
    year    state district  Party
0   2010  haryana  kaithal  major
1   2010  haryana  kaithal    bjp
2   2010  haryana  kaithal   NOTA
3   2010      goa    panji    AAP
4   2010      goa    panji  major
5   2010      goa    panji    BJP
6   2013       up   meerut    INC
7   2013       up   meerut     SP
8   2015  haryana  kaithal    INC
9   2015  haryana  kaithal  major
10  2015  haryana  kaithal    AAP
```